# Simple code to scrape email string in the content HTML with RUBY mail and mechanize

Tags: ruby, email

So far I have this code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require 'mysql2'
require 'mechanize'
require 'mailhandler'
email_receiver = MailHandler.receiver(:imap) do |checker|
checker.address = 'imap.example.com'
checker.port = 993
checker.username = 'username'
checker.password = 'password'
checker.use_ssl  =  true
end
email_receiver.find_email(:by_subject => 'cambio')
```

This returns =>true but when I see the result: it is not complete..

```
# retrieve the body.
email_receiver.search(:email)
```

am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `mailhandler` is a fairly new gem and I doubt that anyone has actually used it. perhaps you should open an issue on github or ask the developers

Comment: what gem would you recommend to use though.